# How to set fields that are not exposed in PodTemplate but available in YAML format for Jenkins?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

For example, `hostname` can be set in YAML format but it's not available in `PodTemplate`. Another example is `volumeMount` against `containerTemplate` that doesn't exist in groovy code.